# sending parameters in call JSONP not working on server

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, iis

Hello I have a problem:
when I do an ajax call using JSONP my local computer everything is fine, but when I run it on my server it shows me an error
Below I show the code and details of the error:

```
$.ajax({

                data: { info: JsonString },
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: "jsonp",
                /*url: jsondata.Ruta + "/LanzarAplicativo/",*/
                url: 'http://localhost:1143/contenido/LanzarAplicativo/',
                success: function (result) {
                    console.log(result);
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    //some code
                }
            });
```

This is the method that is specified in the ajax

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult LanzarAplicativo(string info)
    {
        Informacion info;
        info = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Informacion>(info);

        Session["miContexto"] = informacion ;

        //some code

        return View(); 
    }
```

when I do this the same but changing the url in the ajax (in the url of my IIS server) chrome console throws me the following error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://someUrlmyserver/Plataform/Demo/Contenido/LanzarAplicativo/…%2C%2232%22%3A%22calipso%22%2C%2233%22%3A%22summer%22%7D%7D%7D%7D&_=1382717706500
```

This url is very long due to the number of parameters that ships in the ajax call.

I think the problem could be because of the size of the url but that problem should also go as I run in my localhost

Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: did you include the http get and post protocols in config?

Answer (score 0):

Try using url as /controller/action instead of complete url:

```
$.ajax({
dataType: "jsonp",
url: '/contenido/LanzarAplicativo/',
..
});
```

and instead if returning a view from your controller, you can return a bool (true).

Comment: that url is from another project, that's why I put it that way